# Using an inherited generic type as an input to a method of a type constrained class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, constraints

Edit: changes to make the code better identify the problem.

I'm performance tuning a monte carlo simulation where casting IComponent to IProposition was causing a bottleneck. I've come up with an architect to remove the casting however it isn't working as expected.

The method call in **TryDo** throws a compiler error? (Argument type 'IProposition is not assignable to parameter type 'T')
Why? (IProposition satisfies the constraint on T) and how to fix?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public interface IComponent<T> where T : IComponent<T>
{
    HashSet<T> Inputs { get; }
}

public interface IProposition<T> : IComponent<T> where T : IComponent<T> { }

public interface IAnd<T> : IComponent<T> where T : IComponent<T> {}

class DoStuff<T> where T : IComponent<T>
{
    private void DoIt(T component)
    {
        if (component is IAnd<T>)
            foreach(T input in component.Inputs)
                DoIt(input);
    }

    void TryDo(IProposition<T> proposition)
    {
        DoIt(proposition);
    }
}
```

(I have come up with a separate solution that works using a separate type 'TP' to represent the IProposition - but seems redundant as surely IProposition is a subclass of IComposition)

Comment: Please let us know the compile errors when posting a question.

Comment: Because neither component or preposition are of type T (which DoIt expects). They're of type IComponent of T and IProposition of T. The fact that you've specified that T is IComponent of T isn't something the compiler can infer. Also, IComponent of T is not derived from T. So... yeah.

Comment: You could try *casting* component and proposition to T and see if that throws any invalid cast exceptions. You've got a bit of a complex model going on after all.

Comment: To be honest your model is extremely confusing, what would the purpose of `IComponent<T> where T : IComponent<T>{}` or `IProposition<T> : IComponent<T> where T : IComponent<T>{}` be? Are you sure that this is the model you want?

Comment: Also, can you show at least some possible real world usage of these interfaces? Because basically this model forces each component to be a component of itself or of some other component. What sense does it make? What domain problems does it solve or prevent? Perhaps it would be more useful not to restrict the `T` param in the `IComponent`(or restrict to something else) to allow implementations like `IComponent<IDataAccessService>` etc.

Comment: If you still consider it to be a viable architecture then you should change the `Do` method signature to `private void DoIt(IComponent<T> component)` and rely on the interface references instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to accomplish with such model but **this** code would compile:

```
public interface IComponent<T> where T : IComponent<T> { }

public interface IProposition<T> : IComponent<T> where T : IComponent<T> { }

class DoStuff<T> where T : IComponent<T>
{
    private void DoIt(T component)
    {
    }

    void TryDo(T component, T proposition)
    {
        DoIt(component);
        DoIt(proposition);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure you *entirely* understand how generics work. You seem to have an idea but I really don't see what practical purpose would code like this have.

Now don't take me wrong but you should invest time in studying generics and c# in general with a simpler model. The error in your code was caused by simply supplying a wrong type to `DoIt` method which is a very **beginner** error.

Comment: I've simplified the example by taking out extraneous code.  The TryDo signature encapsulates the usage at a higher level, it is not changeable.